# Celery Task retry on Backend Failure

Tags: celery, celery-task

We are using celery with Redis as the backend and RabbitMQ as the broker.  We ran into an interesting scenario which we don't clearly understand how to recover from.  The order of task execution is as such:

1. Task A is received by celery to be processed
2. Task A is successfully processed by application
3. Celery tries to write 'SUCCESS' as the result state for task A to redis
4. The connection to redis fails and an exception is thrown
5. Celery thinks that the exception is unexpected and marks the Task as failed

There are two things that are not clear to us:
1. How to mark this exception as retryable.  Arguably, this exception is outside the execution-context of our task
2. If Task A is part of a chord, how to ensure that the callback of the chord is called

P.S.: Here is the exception:

`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 435, in trace_task
    uuid, retval, task_request, publish_result,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 146, in mark_as_done
    self.on_chord_part_return(request, state, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 272, in on_chord_part_return
    .expire(tkey, self.expires)                                 \
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 2894, in execute
    return execute(conn, stack, raise_on_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 2749, in _execute_transaction
    connection.send_packed_command(all_cmds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 585, in send_packed_command
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 489, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
ConnectionError: Error -3 connecting to <redis_service>. Temporary failure in name resolution.`